# Run perf without root-rights

Tags: linux, perf

I'm running debian testing with the 4.1 kernel and version 4.1 of the `perf` tool. In this version they seem to have added some sort of protection to keep normal users from collecting data from that tool. So running `perf` as normal user will give this error:

```
perf stat ls
Error:
You may not have permission to collect stats.
Consider tweaking /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid:
 -1 - Not paranoid at all
  0 - Disallow raw tracepoint access for unpriv
  1 - Disallow cpu events for unpriv
  2 - Disallow kernel profiling for unpriv
```

`perf_event_paranoid` contains 3 in my installation. Unfortunately I can't change that file even as root. How can I allow my own user to use `perf` without sudo rights?

I have an application I would like to benchmark which doesn't need root and I don't want to run it as root to benchmark it.

Comment: Does `perf stat -e cycles:u` work? "3" value of `perf_event_paranoid` was added in 2016 https://lwn.net/Articles/696216/ "Disallowing perf_event_open()" and was enabled in "Android and Debian" (also https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/1/11/587 https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1612790 https://www.debian.org/security/2017/dsa-3791)

Comment: @osgx: For me with paranoid level 3 your suggestion does not work, I am still not allowed to use it.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Files in `/proc` that are writable are usually changed by echoing a value into them. You should try:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 >/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid'
```

The files under `/proc/sys/` also have the [sysctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysctl.8.html) command for easy access, so you can instead do:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.perf_event_paranoid=1
```

(though the `-w` for *write* seems to be optional). To ensure this is done at boot time create your own `/etc/sysctl.d/99-mysettings.conf` file with the line

```
kernel.perf_event_paranoid=1
```

Choose a filename that will not override existing files in `/run/sysctl.d/` and `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/`. 
See [man sysctl.d](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysctl.d.5.html).

Comment: To persist across reboots: `sudo sh -c 'echo kernel.perf_event_paranoid=1 > /etc/sysctl.d/local.conf'`

Comment: add the comment to the answer, please

Comment: @Márcio: You want to *append* to `local.conf`, not truncate.  Or write to `/etc/sysctl.d/perf.conf`

Comment: Was able to change the value, but still got the same error (Tried -1,0,1)

Comment: This is also useful reading https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519070/security-implications-of-changing-perf-event-paranoid (setting capabilities for perf) & the discussion it points to https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/perf-security.html